# prove that if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $m^*(A \cup B) \neq m^*(A) + m^*(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The following exercise analyzes the additivity of $m^*$.

a)  Prove that if $A$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then for every $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, it holds that $$m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B)$$.
b) Using the fact that there exists a non-measurable set $E \subseteq [0,1]$, prove that there exist subsets $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that
$A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $$m^*(A \cup B) \neq m^*(A) + m^*(B)$$

proof
a)
For any two sets $A$ and $B$, it holds that

$$ m^*(A \cup B) \leq m^*(A) + m^*(B) $$

Now,
$A \subseteq A \cup B$ and $B \subseteq A \cup B$ by the monotonicity of $m^*$ implies that

$$m^*(A) \leq m^*(A \cup B) $$
$$m^*(B) \leq m^*(A \cup B) $$

Summing up, we obtain

$$m^*(A) + m^*(B) \leq 2m^*(A \cup B) $$

But I don't know how to remove that $2$

for part b) I don have idea how to do it

Comment: To start, (a) is currently false.  Can you check for a typo?

Comment: For b), do you know the form of the Vitali set? If so, what happens if you consider the sets formed by moving Vitali $q$ units to the right, with $q \in\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$?

Comment: @CésarVB but in part a I don´t have that $A \cap B= \emptyset $

Comment: In (a) without $A\cap B=\varnothing$, the thing you are trying to prove is wrong.

Comment: @JulioPuerta I know the Vitali set, that's the one used to demonstrate the existence of a non-measurable subset in $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm not sure if $A \cup B = E$ where $E$ is this Vitali set, or if I have to form A and B  in  this way $q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is $m^*$ measurable, then for each set $E \subset \mathbb R$ we have by the definition

$$m^* (E)=m^*(E\cap A ) + m^*(E \cap A^c).$$

Now, consider the set $A\cup B=E$ and the fact that $A$ is $m^*$ measurable, then we have

\begin{array}
@m^*(A \cup B) &= m^*((A \cup B) \cap A) + m^*((A \cup B)\cap A^c)\\
&=m^*((A \cap A) \cup (B \cap A)) + m^*((A \cap A^c)\cup B \cap A^c)\\
&=m^*(A) + m^*(B \cap A^c)\\
\end{array}

So we have $m^*(A \cup B)=m^*(A) + m^*(B \cap A^c)$ which is not correct for every set $B$.

Sine $A \cap B=\phi$, which implies $B \subset A^c$, then $B \cap A^c=B $. Thus, $m^*(A \cup B)=m^*(A) + m^*(B)$

Comment: The third line of the long display is incorrect. $m^*(B\cap A)$ should be changed to $m^*(A)$ noting that $A\cap A=A$ and $A\cap A^c=\phi$.

Comment: Thanks for your observation.

Comment: Also, the fourth line of the long display $B\cap A$ -> $A$.